# android java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions in android 4.0.4

Tags: android

My app gives

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions
```

this error in Android 4.0.4. Works fine in Later version from this.

When add `android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"`

this in manifest file works fine. But I already have

```
android:name=".misc.WebSession"
```

in manifest. Any Help?

Answer (score 0):

if you have `android:name=".misc.WebSession"` in the `Manifest.xml` file

then set `MultiDex` to `build.gradle` file like this.

```
defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

and compile with

```
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
```